# Do I need to lock HazelcastHttpSession instance when modify its attribute?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cluster-computing, httpsession, hazelcast

I am planing to use Hazelcast for Http session Clustering. I read this document - http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/httpsessionclustering.html and I understand that I need to setup com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter filter and this filter will decorate the original HttpSession to store session data at Hazelcast cache.

**My question is Do I have to put a lock ( distributed lock) on HazelcastHttpSession instance when I modify its attributes like I did for original HttpSession instance.**

If I have to lock HazelcastHttpSession instance, I am planing to use Hazelcast distributed lock, the key to get distributed lock is Session id. Please see my sample code:

```
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
Lock session_lock = hz.getLock( SessionID );

session_lock .lock();
try {
    // Modify session data
} finally {
    session_lock .unlock();
}
```

My application may have 10K users active at a time so the application may need to get 10K distributed lock instance from Hazelcast at a time.

**My question is Hazel ok to to create too many ( 10K ) distributed lock at a time? Any limitation of Hazel distributed lock?** The document http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/lock.html does not mention anything.

Thank you for any comments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to lock the object. Hazelcast datastructures are threadsafe by design. You can however set a deferred-write property so all values are written after the request is finished. They'll not be written if an exception is thrown while processing the request.
If you don't set deferred-write all values are immediately stored inside the distributed session.

Comment: Thanks Noctarius. If we want to do some calls such as getAttribute, setAttribute in one locking transaction, we still need a distributed lock. Is that right?

Comment: What is a locking transaction?

Comment: The locking across some calls suchs as getAttribute and setAttribute.

Comment: As I said, just use deferred-write you have some light transaction around it, there is nothing like a locking transaction.